# Showing circuit error during SPICE simulation of 1N4007 diode

Tags: diodes, spice

I am trying to simulate the following circuit using KiCAD (I currently have version 6.0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faYpbw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

After making the above circuit in schematic editor.I found the spice model of 1N4007 diode was not there in ki cad so i entered the following:

```
.MODEL 1N4007 D( IS=76.9p RS=42.0m BV=1.00k IBV=5.00u
+ CJO=26.5p  M=0.333 N=1.45 TT=4.32u )
```

After that I did: Inspect -> Simulator -> Sim Parameters, in here I put in the following data:

```
Source 1:
Sweep type: V

Source: V1

Starting value: 0 volts

Final value: 10 volts

Increment step: 500m volts
```

Immediately after clicking `ok` it shows the following error:

```
    Note: can't find init file.
******
** ngspice-37 shared library
** Creation Date: Jul 19 2022   06:30:59
******
Error: there is no circuit loaded.
```

If I ignore it and click Run/Stop Simulation, then it shows the following error:

```
Note: No compatibility mode selected!
warning, can't find model '1n4007' from line
d1 net-_r1-pad1_ net-_d1-pad2_ 1n4007
Circuit: KiCad schematic
Error on line 3 or its substitute:
d1 net-_r1-pad1_ net-_d1-pad2_ 1n4007
could not find a valid modelname
Error: circuit not parsed.
```

Can someone please help me find what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The current type is DC

Comment: See [here](https://www.kicad.org/blog/2023/04/KiCad-7.0.2-Release/) in the Spice Simulator section.  There are many recent changes and improvements to the KiCAD spice simulator.  Suggest you try this same circuit on the latest version.

Comment: Thanks @rdtsc. Do you know a way to update KiCAD without redownloading it by any chance?

Comment: Can you show us what you did in KiCad?  Perhaps include a screenshot or something?  I mainly need to know how you added the `.model` statement.  Also keep in mind that unless you're using the simulation-specific diode symbol from the legacy "pspice" library, you'll need to set the "Alternate Node Sequence" to `2 1`.